# Expresiones regulares para encontrar una palabra sin importar que esté en mayusculas o minúsculas

Tags: python, regex

Estoy intentando encontrar una palabra sin considerar que esté en mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Por ejemplo necesito buscar la palabra mundo (sin importar que esté en mayúsculas o minúsculas usando expresiones regulares:

```
texto = "Hola mundo del MUNDO donde MuNdO es mi munDO"

b = re.findall(r'mundo+', texto)
```

No logro obtener las palabras mundo MUNDO MuNdO munDO

Agradezco vuestra guía!

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1):

Para Para una coincidencia insensible a las mayúsculas y minúsculas. puedes añadir como tercer argumento el flag `re.IGNORECASE`

asi:

```py
import re
texto = "Hola mundo del MUNDO donde MuNdO es mi munDO"

b = re.findall('mundo+', texto, re.IGNORECASE)
```

resultado:

```
['mundooo', 'MUNDO', 'MuNdO', 'munDO']
```

Comment: y por ejemplo si yo quisiera encontrar del texto = "Hola mundo del MUNDOs donde MuNdO es mi munDOs" y quiero encontrar las palabras word o wolrds(sea mayúsculas o minúsculas), entonces esta correcto hacer así?     b = re.findall('mundo+ | mundos+', texto, re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: Así es, Francisco, o también podrías hacerlo asi: `re.findall('mundos?', texto, re.IGNORECASE)` La `?` al final significa *coincidencia de cero o uno* es decir, que la `s` al final puede estar o no estar presente. Como ves, regex te brinda varias formas de hacer lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias, Brillante aporte!! saludos!

Comment: Una cosulta, si quiero encontrar exactamente la palabra sid, sin importar si está en mayusculs y minúsculas!! 
text = "hola soy Sid de Sidnia pero me dican sid"
re.findall("[[\s]war[\s]", text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: En ese caso pones la palabra exacta asi: `re.findall("sid", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`, sin embargo, tambien coincidirá el Sid dentro de la palabra `Sidnia` para evitar ese caso, puede usar el limite de palabra `\b` asi: `re.findall("sid\b", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`.
Te recomiendo esta guia en español https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfogZfIS03U, recuerdo haberla visto hace tiempo y me ayudo aclarar este tema

Comment: Gracias saludos !